# How to tell NSPredicate skip entities before context.save()

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predicate

How to prevent firing controller(*:didChangeContentWith: diff) before viewContext was saved?
After creating an NSManagedObject object i'm getting controller(*:didChangeContentWith: diff) fired, and after saving context too, so it fires twice for the same object.

First of all, I create NSFetchedResultsController and set fetchRequest.predicate

```
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = nil
```

Then when I add item:

```
let newItem = Item(context: context) //controller fires right after this #1
...
...
context.save() // Fires here too #2
```

First time objectID is wrong yet, second time it's correct and set up according to the context. So, **is there any way to tell predicate to skip entities, that was created before context.save()?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found for now is filtering results. It works for me because I have own custom logic of UI updating, not sure it will work for everyone.

```
lists = fetchLists().filter { !$0.objectID.isTemporaryID }
```

Where **lists** is [NSManagedObject] (subclass). So when CoreData was changed, I simply fetch with needed predicate and filter out all temporary IDs. When item gets correct ID, controller(:didChangeContentWith: diff) fires again and everything works fine.

Still looking for the way to fetch with skipping **isTemporaryID** objects.